# Flux.jl: Understanding iris dataset download source code. Why SHA256 hashing is used?

Tags: machine-learning, julia

While going through the dataset download source code in Flux.jl github repository
(https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/src/data/Data.jl),

The Full source code:

```
module Data

import ..Flux
import SHA

export CMUDict, cmudict

deps(path...) = joinpath(@__DIR__, "..", "..", "deps", path...)

function download_and_verify(url, path, hash)
    tmppath = tempname()
    download(url, tmppath)
    hash_download = open(tmppath) do f
        bytes2hex(SHA.sha256(f))
    end
    if hash_download !== hash
        msg  = "Hash Mismatch!\n"
        msg *= "  Expected sha256:   $hash\n"
        msg *= "  Calculated sha256: $hash_download"
        error(msg)
    end
    mv(tmppath, path; force=true)
end

function __init__()
  mkpath(deps())
end

include("mnist.jl")
export MNIST

include("fashion-mnist.jl")
export FashionMNIST

include("cmudict.jl")
using .CMUDict

include("tree.jl")
include("sentiment.jl")
using .Sentiment

include("iris.jl")
export Iris


end
```

I couldn't understand what the following lines **do** and **why** they are needed,

```
    hash_download = open(tmppath) do f
        bytes2hex(SHA.sha256(f))
    end
    if hash_download !== hash
        msg  = "Hash Mismatch!\n"
        msg *= "  Expected sha256:   $hash\n"
        msg *= "  Calculated sha256: $hash_download"
        error(msg)
    end
```

The following code is being used by iris.jl (a script to download the iris dataset), in this context,

```
download_and_verify("$(cache_prefix)https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data",
                        deps("iris.data"),
                        "6f608b71a7317216319b4d27b4d9bc84e6abd734eda7872b71a458569e2656c0")
```

I would be grateful if someone could clarify what the hashing section of the code does and why they are needed.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a `Flux.jl` developer, but that's a pretty standard way to verify the [integrity of a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File_verification&oldid=939264606#Integrity_verification) downloaded from the Web

Comment: Just to confirm whether I understand correctly or not : I precompute the SHA256 representation of the contents of a file and check them against the SHA256 calculated from the contents of the downloaded file?

Comment: In these cases, usually the person who generate the data computes the hash locally, before uploading to the web, and makes the information available to everyone.  For example, if you go to the download page of Julia https://julialang.org/downloads/ you'll find the link to get the MD5 and SHA256 hashes